# cannot git push due to unrelated upstream file changes

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

We have a central repo, with 10+ devs working on it.

I'm helping my buddy (he's OOO) to merge his PR into `master`. Due to another PR that got merged first, there's a merge conflict for his PR now. All I needed to do was to check out his branch, rebase it on current `master`, resolve all conflicts, commit, `git push` to his remote feature branch and updated the PR, get it merged.

Simple as that, what drives me nuts is: whenever after I've resolved all conflicts, hit `git rebase --continue`, and then I do `git push`, it's giving me this error:

```
On branch this_is_cool_branch
Your branch and 'origin/this_is_cool_branch' have diverged,
and have 2698 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Following its instructions, I do `git pull`, then it pulls in a whole bunch of changes which were unrelated with my changes/conflicts at all, they're actually the other teams' changes. Then it asks me to

```
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

I've absolutely no clue why this is happening, please help.

Here are my steps:

1. `git clone master_branch`
2. `git checkout this_is_cool_branch` (`this_is_cool_branch` is my buddy's branch in the remote)
3. `git rebase master`
4. manually resolved all conflicts
5. `git rebase --continue`
6. `git status` (annoyingly it gives me below error)

   On branch this_is_cool_branch
   Your branch and 'origin/this_is_cool_branch' have diverged,
   and have 2698 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
     (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

   nothing to commit, working tree clean
7. `git pull`, the aforementioned nightmare happens. Tons of unrelated changes got pulled in and asking me to fix merge conflicts.

Which step did I miss? Which git command did I use it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the few cases that the default git advice is the opposite of what you what. As with everything else in git, it's about what you want your history graph to look like at the end of the operation.

In short, you need to do `git push --force` at the end of your rebase instead of `git pull`.

Here's why:

```
                 master
                    |
                    v
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
      \
       F -- G -- H
                 ^
                 |
    coolbranch, origin/coolbranch
```

Before the rebase, your history looks like this. `A-E` is master, which diverged from your branch starting with `B` due to the conflicting pull request. Here is what happens after the rebase:

```
                 master
                    |
                    v
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F' -- G' -- H'
      \                              ^
       F -- G -- H                   |
                 ^              coolbranch
                 |
        origin/coolbranch
```

As you can see, pushing local `coolbranch` directly to the version on the server just doesn't make much sense any more. Instead, you want to tell the server to accept your rebased commits `F'-H'` and move the branch label of `coolbranch` over to `H'`. That's exactly what `push --force` (or `-f` for short) does.

If you try to do a `git pull` after the rebase but before `git push -f`, you will be attempting to merge `H` into `H'` which will basically undo all your rebase changes.

So the final procedure should be something like this:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull` Now you have the newly merged PR
3. `git checkout coolbranch`
4. `git pull coolbranch` Or whatever you use to sync your local `coolbranch` with your buddy's work.
5. `git rebase master`
6. Fix conflicts and continue until done.
7. Optional `git status`. The output you show is correct and expected it's giving you the number of commits between `B` and `H` in `origin/coolbranch` and `B` and `H'` in newly rebased `coolbranch`. If the numbers look sensible in that context (e.g., they differ by the number of commits in the conflicting PR), then your rebase was probably good.
8. `git push -f`

After that, you should be ready to submit a conflict-free pull request. Any time `master` changes out from under you, just repeat these steps.

Comment: @Tim. Better now?

Comment: Yes +1 and thanks for also correcting the `git clone` step, which made no sense  ^ ^.

Comment: Boom, this is awesome! Following your steps helped me fix my issue, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Fisher Glad it helped. This is one of the most common use cases I had trouble with when I started with git as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for making it so clear by drawing this graph, I made me crazy and wasted me 3 hours on this.

Comment: @Fisher no problem. I've been there myself. Always just remember that's got commands are tools to manipulate the graph. You really care about what the graph looks like, not which commands you run. Most tasks have multiple possible solutions. Nowadays for anything out of the ordinary I just sit down and draw the picture first.

Comment: Yes! That's so true, I was trying to draw the diagram out myself, but I was not completely sure what's happening behind the scenes after I ran `git rebase master` and `git rebase --continue`